# How to use win32gui.ReleaseDC(,)

Tags: python

I get an `error('GetPixel', 'No error message is available')` when I use the code:
`color = win32gui.GetPixel(win32gui.GetDC(win32gui.GetActiveWindow()), x , y)`.

As I understood, I should release DC (win32gui.ReleaseDC(,)) every time I use GetPixel. But what should I use as a handle to window and a handle to device context?

As I understand, I can get a handle to window by using win32gui.GetActiveWindow(), right? But I have no idea how to get a handle to device context.

The code:

```
def get_position_and_color():
    a=0
    while a<=3:
        sleep(1)
        x, y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
        color = win32gui.GetPixel(win32gui.GetDC(win32gui.GetActiveWindow()), x , y)
        print(str(a)+' '+str(x)+','+str(y)+','+str(color))
        # print(a)
        a=a+1


get_position_and_color()
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here in the end?

Comment: For one, `GetCursorPos()` returns screen coordinates; if you call `GetDC()` with a HWND, that DC's coordinates will not be screen coordinates and `GetPixel()` may try to access things out of bounds.

Comment: I'm using this code to detect buttons by color and press them. It's the only option (most of the buttons are located on the remote computer and I have access to it via remote desktop). It have been working well enough untill that error emerged. Now I cannot use getpixel AT ALL.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help @AKX.
I guess I found the answer.
I have the same code in VBA and it never fails, but in python...
I just compared the two codes.
VBA:

lDC = GetWindowDC(0)
Call GetCursorPos(pLocation)
lColour = GetPixel(lDC, pLocation.x, pLocation.y)
Debug.Print (i & "=" & pLocation.x & "=" & pLocation.y & "=" & lColour & "=")

Python (see above)
I used win32gui.GetActiveWindow() instead of "0". I guess the coordinates were out of the boundaries of the "activewindow".

Comment: Yeah, `GetDC(NULL)` returns the screen DC. Glad you found the answer!